# i want to echo the values from index 3 to 5 in an associative array, couldn's figure it out,

Tags: php, arrays

my array is

```
$ar=array('A'=>'1','B'=>'2','C'=>'3','D'=>'4','E'=>'5','F'=>'6','G'=>'7','H'=>'8','I'=>'9');

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{ echo $value; }
```

This echoes all the values, i want to echo from index 3 to 5.

Comment: you have not index  3 ...  5  you  have index form A  ...  to I

Comment: do you want to search by **keys** OR **values**?

Comment: i want to print both key and values like :- C=>3   D=>4    E=>5

Comment: Just add a counter in your foreach that starts on 0. If >=3 && <=5  echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array contains values in consecutive numeric order - `array_slice` would be the simplest approach:

```
$result = array_slice($ar, 2, 3);
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [C] => 3
    [D] => 4
    [E] => 5
)
```

**----------**

To print the result as key/value pairs:

```
foreach (array_slice($ar, 2,3) as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => $v" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output:

```
C => 3
D => 4
E => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could  use array_values   for convert you associative array in  a numeric indexed  array and then loop over

```
$my_array = array_values($array);


for ($i = 2; $i <=4; i++) {
 if (isset($my_array[$i])){
   echo $my_array[$i] . '<br />';
  }
}
```

or you can use use array_slice

```
  $start= 2; 
  $elem = 3

   foreach(array_slice($temp_row, $start, $elem) as $key => $value) {

       echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br>';
   }
```

Comment: answer updated  with check for a valid value in indexed  array

Comment: This will output values from keys D-F in OP's example array, not C-E has asked for.